# Multiple check item send params

Tags: android, json

I have set switch box in adapter when switch box is enable then open custom check box list item. I have select check box item multiple. This switch box design when select spinner item and then open fragment page. When select multiple check box item and send JSON param like this:

```
"attendees": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "person": "xza"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "person": "cfd"
      }
    ]
```

And send button applying in activity. Spinner and save button design in activity and select item design in fragment.

I have make model class like:

```
public class MeetingModel {

public String date;
public String time;
public boolean reminder;
public boolean assignTOther;
public boolean contactTo;
public boolean attendeesTo;
public String remark;
private MeetingReminder meetingReminder;
private int assignid;
private int contactid;
private List<Assigne> attendees = null;
private int attendeesid;
private String location;
private String purpose;
private String clientType;
private String id;
private String logSubType;

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public boolean isReminder() {
    return reminder;
}

public void setReminder(boolean reminder) {
    this.reminder = reminder;
}

public boolean isAssignTOther() {
    return assignTOther;
}

public void setAssignTOther(boolean assignTOther) {
    this.assignTOther = assignTOther;
}

public boolean isContactTo() {
    return contactTo;
}

public void setContactTo(boolean contactTo) {
    this.contactTo = contactTo;
}

public boolean isAttendeesTo() {
    return attendeesTo;
}

public void setAttendeesTo(boolean attendeesTo) {
    this.attendeesTo = attendeesTo;
}

public String getRemark() {
    return remark;
}

public void setRemark(String remark) {
    this.remark = remark;
}

public MeetingReminder getMeetingReminder() {
    return meetingReminder;
}

public void setMeetingReminder(MeetingReminder meetingReminder) {
    this.meetingReminder = meetingReminder;
}

public int getAssignid() {
    return assignid;
}

public void setAssignid(int assignid) {
    this.assignid = assignid;
}

public int getContactid() {
    return contactid;
}

public void setContactid(int contactid) {
    this.contactid = contactid;
}

public void setMeetingReminder(String date, String time) {
    MeetingReminder meetingReminder = new MeetingReminder();
    meetingReminder.setDate(date);
    meetingReminder.setTime(time);
    setMeetingReminder(meetingReminder);

}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public String getPurpose() {
    return purpose;
}

public void setPurpose(String purpose) {
    this.purpose = purpose;
}

public String getClientType() {
    return clientType;
}

public void setClientType(String clientType) {
    this.clientType = clientType;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getLogSubType() {
    return logSubType;
}

public void setLogSubType(String logSubType) {
    this.logSubType = logSubType;
}


public List<Assigne> getAttendees() {
    return attendees;
}

public void setAttendees(List<Assigne> attendees) {
    this.attendees = attendees;
}

public JsonArray getCheckedItems(){
    List<Assigne>  tmpList=new ArrayList<>();
    List<Assigne> attendees = new ArrayList<>();
    JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
    for(Assigne attendee:attendees){
        if(attendee.isHeaderSelected()){
            tmpList.add(attendee);
            attendee.setHeaderSelected(true);
            JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
            obj.addProperty("id", attendee.getId());
            obj.addProperty("name", attendee.getName());
            jsonArray.add(obj);
        }
    }
    return jsonArray;
}
}
```

I expect the output is:

> "attendees":[{"id":"1","person":"fff"},{"id":"2","person":"dfdf"}]

But the actual output is:

> "attendees": []

Comment: `attendees` is empty that's why . you just created empty list and looped `foreach` in it.

Comment: you have the same variable names for both List local and global, attendees. try replacing for(Assigne attendee:attendees) by for(Assigne attendee:this.attendees) or for(Assigne attendee:getAttendees())